# Check if unpaired bluetooth device is in range by MAC adress iOS/objective-C

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, bluetooth

I would like to be able to write an app on iPhone which can check if a bluetooth device is in range. I will only know the MAC adress of the device which I would like to check. The devices will not be paired. Is there any way to write such an app and get it through the appstore?

greetings,
jarektb

Comment: I think that you can't access the MAC address of a Bluetooth peripheral. Plus Bluetooth peripherals are managed by iOS.